# jQuery on back button find hash tag and fire click event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on my website that allows people to post content (similar to a twitter) and am trying to make it more streamline via jQuery/Ajax. There is many categories that people can choose to post in and each is organized by the main category, or section if you will.

Every time a user clicks on a section in the navigation panel to the left, that item moves up to the top of the list and expands downward displaying all of the categories in that section. Another thing that happens is the main content area fades out and in with the new content (the user posts) belonging to that section and categories. This has been going great so far and looks awesome!

However, say you click on a section and category to see all of the posts in that specific category. Then you click on a post to go inside of the post and see all the information, comments, etc.. Now, you want to go back to where you were so you hit your back button. When doing this right now it is going back and displaying the main page details again, not the category you had previously selected to look through.

I have added the following code to display which category is select (example: "/#/community") and to also check the hash then fire the "click" event to trigger that category to be shown once again.

```
last_known_hash = location.hash;
window.setInterval(function() {
    if(last_known_hash != location.hash) {
        $('#categories-panel a[name="'+ location.hash.substring(2) +'"]').click();
        last_known_hash = location.hash;
    }
}, 500);
```

Upon clicking back it does still show the "#/community" in the URL, however it does not fire the click. This is odd because if you type in the "#/community" into the URL it does work properly. So I am not really sure on why it's not being triggered properly on clicking "back". I'm not sure if this is the best/right way to go about doing this, but it's all I could think of at the moment. Maybe do a session instead? As always, any help would be appreciated :)

P.S. I know the click event works on it's own as when I run it in firebug it works perfectly.

SUMMARY: When someone clicks "back" in their browser, I need it to go to where they were last, Example: sitehere.com/#/community - and then fire a click event to display the "community" category content once again.

Comment: It's a little hard to find the actual *practical/answerable question* is, perhaps you could summarize that at the end? Semi-related, perhaps something like [YUI Browser History](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/history/) is what you need?

Comment: added a summary, hope it helps! If not let me know. I am also trying to stay away from HTML 5 as there's too many browsers that simply don't support it yet.

Comment: SetInterval is always gunna have hiccups for waiting. Should use a callback instead...

Comment: Any examples of using a callback instead?

Answer (score 1):

historyJS and HTML5 history popState and pushState. Those are the terms you need to learn to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is there any other way around that? I am trying to stay away from HTML 5 since there's too many browsers that don't support it yet. Which is why I am trying the good ol' hash method, haha.

Comment: You should use HTML5 AND HistoryJS... historyJS is a polyfill made for browsers that don't support pushState and popState. It's important to use both, as you also want to ensure progressive enhancement too.

Comment: ah didn't know that. I noticed github uses this method, yet it still doesn't work in IE?

Comment: This should work in IE. HistoryJS was built for IE (well not specifically, just non-html5 browsers). Just kind of have to start out developing for both, and make sure the historyJS stuff can be deprecated out of your code later without too much pain.

Comment: Well then...guess I should brush up on HTML5, lol. Thanks. Any where you recommend on learning the whole HTML 5 + HistoryJS combo?

Comment: HTML5 is the easy stuff... the historyJS is a little more complex. It depends on what you're doing that you'll need history states. You kind of have to start implementing it, and break it to figure this one out as there is no real standard. I strongly recommend just making a page that ajax's out a center div like an iFrame and pushing history states in a test environemnt from both. HTML5 and the library. Remember HTML5 is not 'processes and methods' it's attributes recognized by the DOM interpreter to have certain properties.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that the whole "HTML5" history ordeal has nothing to do with actual HTML...lol. Is it only the HTML5 DOCTYPE that is needed to make this work? (obviously with the JS involved and everything)

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange solves your problem